# Blender renders always frame 1 on 2nd computer

Tags: rendering, performance

I'm using a second computer to CPU cycle render an animation on Windows 10. I have the "common" setup to use the same project file (network drive mapped) on both computers with the same output directory, same Blender version, same OS version, render single PNGs, unticked overwrite and ticked placeholders. While the computers pick the right frame numbers to render, the second computer always renders the first frame (into the picked frame number). Any idea what I could do wrong ?

The preview on the second computer looks right in every display mode but single rendering one frame seems also to be animation messed up (wrong position) when I jump to a frame number and render this single frame (but I assume that this is also the case with just one computer).

Any help would be great !

EDIT:
I have recognized, that both computers use the same blendcache directory, could this be a problem ?

Answer (score 1):

I answer the question on myself. I can't excatly describe what the problem was, but I...

a) updated from Blender 2.79 to 2.80 beta
b) baked animations and physics
c) corrected dope sheet animations with start and end points

As side effect I have a ~5x performace gain, what is great, I'm not sure if the new blender or the baked animations did this.
Now parallel computation on 2 notebooks and 1 desktop runs fine, resulting in another ~3x performance gain. :-)